# Java PreparedStatement, what to expect when the batchExecute does not have any parameter?

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception, prepared-statement

I am receiving a NullPointerException in a method. The only part that I'm suspicious about is that I may have not any parameter added to my prepared statement. The code is as follows

```
try {
  String sql = "update myTable set Name = 'valid' where startDate = ?";
  myPrepStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  for(Date date : dateList) {
    myPrepStatement.setDate(1,date);
    myPrepStatement.addBatch();
  } 
  myPrepStatement.executeBatch();
}
catch (Exception e){

}
```

Assuming that conn is correctly set and all the other variables are appropriately initialized. If dateList is empty, is it possible for me to receive a NullPointerException?
Thanks

Comment: You could post the exception stack trace.

Comment: Why are you assuming everything else to be correct? please paste the logs here.

Comment: JDBC is a minefield if you make any assumptions. It could throw an exception, it could hang indefinably, or it could fail silently.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke JDBC is not the minefield but those vendors whose implementation don't follow the standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```
public interface PreparedStatement extends Statement
```

> If dateList is empty, is it possible for me to receive a
>   NullPointerException?

So if you want to be 100% sure, you should dig into a JDBC Driver implementation code.

For example, MariaDB JDBC driver implementation:

```
public void addBatch() throws SQLException {
    if (this.batchPreparedStatements == null) {
        this.batchPreparedStatements = new ArrayList();
    }
    this.batchPreparedStatements.add(new MySQLPreparedStatement(
            this.connection, this.sql, this.dQuery,
            this.useFractionalSeconds));
}
```

MySQL JDBC driver implementation:

```
public synchronized void addBatch()
    throws SQLException
  {
    if (this.batchedArgs == null) {
      this.batchedArgs = new ArrayList();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.parameterValues.length; ++i) {
      checkAllParametersSet(this.parameterValues[i], this.parameterStreams[i], i);
    }

    this.batchedArgs.add(new BatchParams(this.parameterValues, this.parameterStreams, this.isStream, this.streamLengths, this.isNull));
  }
```

Comment: If you go to the implementation details, you should also post `executeBatch` implementation which is the method that could throw the NPE, not `addBatch` since this method won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

> If dateList is empty, is it possible for me to receive a `NullPointerException`?

This will depend on the JDBC implementation for the `PreparedStatement` interface.

But generally speaking, if `dateList` is empty, then no batch operation is added to the `PreparedStatement` so when executing `executeBatch` it should execute nothing, and no exception should raise.